# 404 Bad Request while posting json object to server

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, ajax, controller

I am trying to pass a json object to server via ajax calls.But it is throwing 404 Bad Request. Actually I have a form, and i am converting this form data to json object. In table i have set id as primary key which is auto incremented, and my form doesnt have field id.
This is my controller

```
     var Bus= angular.module('Bus',[]);


   Bus.controller('BusController',function($scope,$http) {

$scope.business = {}

$scope.submitMyForm=function(){
       console.log($scope.business);
        var q=JSON.stringify($scope.business)  
         console.log(q)

            $

            .ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : " some url",
                data :JSON.stringify($scope.business),

                success: function(){
                          alert('success');
                           },

                error : function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    alert('oops!!');
                },
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : "application/json"
            });
        };
});
```

How to resolve the issue?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

404 Not Found or
400 Bad Request?

If it is actually throwing 404 your URL is wrong. If it is 400:

Have you checked with your debugger to see if the `$scope.business` object actually contains all the correct values?

On a side note: You should not make these requests in an angular controller but use a service instead:

```
    Bus.service('MyService', function($http) {
      function postForm(form) {
        var data = angular.toJSON(form);
        // proceed with the $http stuff ...
      }
      return {
        postForm: postForm
      };
    });
```

And inject the service in your controller and call it like this:

```
    Bus.controller('BusController',function($scope, MyService) {
      $scope.submitMyForm = function() {
          MyService.postForm($scope.business);
      };
    });
```

In any way it would be helpful to know the JSON format your backend expects and the JSON that is produced by your client to understand what's wrong.